# Doctrine query for authentication

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, dql

Consider this query:

```
$query = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')
      ->createQuery('u')
      ->innerJoin('u.Groups g')
      ->where('u.name = 'username')
      ->adnWhere('g.name <> 'groupname')
```

This return a user with 'username' regardless of his 'groupname'. I need to only return a user if he does NOT have a 'groupname' relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the WITH keyword in your inner join. This basically add conditions to the implicit ON clause of the inner join.

```
$query = Doctrine::getTable('sfGuardUser')
      ->createQuery('u')
      ->innerJoin("u.Groups g WITH g.name <> 'groupname'")
      ->where('u.name = 'username')
```

[More info here.](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/en#join-syntax%3awith-keyword)